# Remove string tail from first occurrence of a symbol

Tags: python

I need to remove comment (**if it exists**) from a string. Comments start with `#`.

Line may have multiple `#`.
E.g., "separator" line: `################################`

Is there a better (one-liner) way to do it than this:

```
    ipound = line.find('#')
    if ipound >= 0:
        line = line[: ipound].rstrip()
```

(`rstrip` is optional to remove white space before comment)

PS: cannot avoid `if` like this:

```
>>> line = "test"
>>> line = line[:line.find('#')]
>>> line
'tes'
```

Comment: you can use `split` like `bar = line.split('#')[0]` it'll remove comment after `#`

Comment: `ipound = line.lstrip('# ')` will remove # and any leading spaces. `rstrip` removes spaces from the end of the line, not the start.

Comment: @DavidBuck correct, but that's not what OP wants

Comment: @Hippolippo It will fail if the line does not contain '#'.

Comment: `line = line[:line.index("#")] if "#" in line else line`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be remove the comment and return the line.

```
def remove_comment(line):
    return line.split('#')[0].rstrip()
```

Comment: This was also mentioned by @Fahim Ahmed as a first comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

`line.index("#")` returns the first occurrence of "`#`"

You can then use string slicing to get the stuff before it: `line = line[:line.index("#")]`
If there is no instance of "`#`", this will cause an error, so instead do `line = line[:line.index("#")] if "#" in line else line`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the end of the string, I would advise you to use the [re library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You can do a lot of complicated stuff with one line of code.

Removing what is after `#` if there is a `#` is equivalent to keeping all of what is before `#` and everything if there is no `#`.

```
import re 

string='hi#there'
new_string=re.findall('.*#?',string)[0]

>>>new_string='hi'

string2='hithere'
new_string_2=re.findall('.*#?',string2)[0]

>>>new_string='hithere'
```

You did not specify if you were going to have many `#` in your string. If yes, it will only consider the last `#`.

```
string3='hi#there#how are you ?'
new_string_3=re.findall('.*#',strign3)[0]

>>>new_string_3='hi#there#
```